# C - Proper way to close files when using both open() and fdopen()

Tags: c, unix, file-io, memory-leaks

So I'm building a Unix minishell in C, and am implementing input, output, and err redirection, and have come across a problem with files. I open my files in a loop where I find redirection operators, and use open(), which returns an fd. I then assign the child's fd accordingly, and call an execute function.

When my shell is just going out and finding programs, and executing them with execvp(), I don't have much of a problem. The only problem is knowing whether or not I need to call close() on the file descriptors before prompting for the next command line. I'm worried about having an fd leak, but don't exactly understand how it works.

My real problem arises when using builtin commands. I have a builtin command called "read", that takes one argument, an environmental variable name(could be one that doesn't yet exist). Read then prompts for a value, and assigns that value to the variable. Here's an example:

```
% read TESTVAR
test value test value test value
% echo  ${TESTVAR}
test value test value test value
```

Well lets say that I try something like this:

```
% echo here's another test value > f1
% read TESTVAR < f1
% echo  ${TESTVAR}
here's another test value
```

This works great, keep in mind that read executes inside the parent process, I don't call read with execvp since it's builtin. Read uses gets, which requires a stream variable, not an fd. So after poking around on the irc forums a bit I was told to use fdopen, to get the stream from the file descriptor. So before calling gets, I call:

```
rdStream = fdopen(inFD, "r");
```

then call

```
if(fgets(buffer, envValLen, rdStream) != buffer) 
{
    if(inFD) fclose(rdStream);
    return -1;
}
if(inFD) fclose(rdStream);
```

As you can see, at the moment I'm closing the stream with fclose(), unless it is equal to stdin(which is 0). Is this necessary? Do I need to close the stream? Or just the file descriptor? Or both? I'm quite confused on which I should close, since they both refer to the same file, in a different manner. At the moment I'm not closing the fd, however I think that I definitely should. I would just like somebody to help make sure my shell isn't leaking any files, as I want it to be able to execute several thousand commands in a single session without leaking memory.

Thanks, if you guys want me to post anymore code just ask.

Answer (score 14):

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fclose.html) says:

> The fclose() function **shall perform the equivalent of a `close()`** on the
>   file descriptor that is associated with the stream pointed to by
>   stream.

So calling `fclose` is enough; it will also close the descriptor.

Comment: Will calling close in addition be bad? There are many cases in which I don't think the file descriptor will close inside the command, for example if I call "echo abc > f1", echo won't close f1 will it? So I need to call close inside my shell each time redirection is used.


Knowing that this is happening, do I still need to close the stream? I'm guessing I do since calling fclose will need to flush the buffers and whatnot.

Comment: @Scriptonaut The standard doesn't mention it. My guess is that `close` will return `-1` but technically the behavior is undefined. So you could devise a scheme where after a `fclose` you also set the associated descriptor to `-1`. Then a `close` will fail cleanly with `EBADF`. Even better: don't mix standard I/O with low-level I/O.

Comment: Ya, I would rather get away from high level IO since my shell mostly relies on low level stuff. Are there functions like gets that take fd's instead of streams?


Anyways, thanks for the help, I think I got it mostly figured out.

Comment: @Scriptonaut No, there's no function like `fgets` unfortunately

Comment: Calling `close` in addition is **very bad**. It's a type of double-free bug. In single-threaded programs without signal handlers, you probably won't run into trouble, but if there's any chance of another file getting opened between the `fclose` and the `close`, you'll accidentally close an unrelated file and badly mess up the state of your program. This can lead to dangerous file-corruption bugs.

Comment: @R.. Ah, haven't thought about reusing the descriptor, indeed.

Comment: @R: Well darn, I have multiple threads. What should I do in this case? Why isn't there a way to get the stream of an fd without opening the entire thing, like the complement of fileno()? fdopen() seems like a really bad way to accomplish this, all I want is the name of the stream, I don't want to open the file twice.

Answer (score 2):

`FILE` is a buffering object from standard C library. When you do `fclose` (standard C function) it will eventually call `close` (Unix system function) but only after making sure C library buffers are flushed. So, I would say, if you use `fopen` and`fwrite` then you should use `fclose`, and not just `close`, otherwise you risk loosing some data.

Comment: Ok. I think I will need to call close() in the main loop in the shell, because there are many cases where the cmd's themselves won't look after closing the files, such as "echo abc > f1". Knowing that I will need to call close() in the main loop, I'm guessing then that I will still need to call fclose() inside read because fclose does other higher level things like you said. This would all be quite a bit easier if I didn't need a file stream to get a line of input. Thanks.

Comment: I think calling `fclose` once is enough. Also, notice that open files are closed (call to `close`) automatically when process dies.

Comment: Won't I need to call close in the case that I'm not using fdopen()? This will happen often in this shell. My shell doesn't call a process for every command, sometimes it executes it right in the parent process.

Comment: Ok, in this case I think you have two options: either use FILE objects only, or use both file descriptors and FILE but keep track what is what and use appropriate function to close them.